# Exception when sending file through Stream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, dropbox-api, access-token, filestreamresult

I want to download a file directly from dropbox.I am able to retrieve the contents of a file which I want to download directly from dropbox.I am unable to send the file through stream to a browser.
Following exception:
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\FirstLab_1.pdf' is denied.
at the line
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))

Following is my code:

```
public FileStreamResult Download(string bkpath)
{

    string bookname = bkpath;
    var accessToken = new OAuthToken("d2iwy26brzqhetr0", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    var api = new DropboxApi(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, accessToken);
    var file = api.DownloadFile("dropbox", bookname);
    string path = file.Path;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
    // Create random data to write to the file. 
    byte[] dataArray = new byte[file.Data.Length];
    new Random().NextBytes(dataArray);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        // Write the data to the file, byte by byte. 
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
        {
            fileStream.WriteByte(dataArray[i]);
        }

        // Set the stream position to the beginning of the file.
        fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Read and verify the data. 
        for (int i = 0; i < fileStream.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dataArray[i] != fileStream.ReadByte())
            {
                Response.Write("Error writing data."); 
            }
        }
        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Please help me out to get the file download direcly from dropbox as I am resolving this exception for a about long time and couldn't get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The exception message describes the problem pretty well. Simply either

a) Right click on 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\' folder -> Properties -> Security and give the write permission to everyone.

or **much better**

b) write the file into the temp directory.

```
string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(path));
```